# How to display the list of books of a user in php code

Tags: sql, request

I am a beginner in programming.

I want to create a site in which I would like to display the list of books of a user that he has previously added. here is the schema of the code.

```
table book;
id ,name,detail ,urlimage.
table users;
id,name,email,password. 
table add_book;
uses_id INT ,book_id INT , key primary (users_id ,book_id ).
```

I have three tables in my database; the book table, the users table and the add_book table. their structures is given in the above question add_book.users_id and add_book.book_id are foreign keys. I would like to make sure that when a user adds a book to his list, an entry is created in the add_book table with the request. ('INSERT INTO kal224_sory.add_book (users_id, book_id) VALUES (: users,: book)'); $ sql-> execute (['users' => $ users_id, 'book' => $ book_id]); .It works well where there is problem, I try to send in json the fields of the table book that correspond to book_id which have the same entries users_id where(add_book.users_id = $ users_id) of the table add_book. the code I tried is;

Comment: thanks for your, I reformulated my question to be more explicit then help me please

Answer (score 0):

You need to `SELECT` the data from the `add_book` table that belongs to a particular `uses_id` (sp.)

```
SELECT * FROM add_book WHERE uses_id = 1 -- change '1' to whatever user's ID you'd like to view data for
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i rephrase my question to be more explicit so help me please